# AndroidKeyStore no such provider

Tags: android, android-keystore, java-security

I'm just trying to get a basic example of the [Android Key Store system](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#UsingAndroidKeyStore) to generate a symmetric key. I followed the example in the tutorial (using Kotlin) but I get an error like so:

> java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: AndroidKeyStore

Below is my code where the compiler is throwing an error:

```
val kpg: KeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES", "AndroidKeyStore")
```

On my Gradle, I am using compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 28. I'm also have a minSdkVersion of 25. All of which should satisfy the Android's doc on using the AndroidKeyStore (min API level 18).

If I remove the provider, everything works like planned, since I'm assuming it goes to the default provider. The same goes for the KeyPairGenerator and KeyStore classes when I try the AndroidKeyStore provider.

Am I using the wrong provider keyword? Or is there some additional setup that I'm supposed to be doing?

Thanks,

Update 1 - So I kept searching and found that you can get a list of available providers on my system. Here's my code below:

```
for (p in Security.getProviders()) {
        //Log.d(TAG, String.format("== %s ==", p.getName()))
        println(String.format("== %s ==", p.getName()))
        println(String.format("%s", p.info))
//            for (s in p.getServices()) {
//                //Log.d(TAG, String.format("- %s", s.getAlgorithm()))
//                println(String.format("- %s", s.getAlgorithm()))
//            }
    }
```

Also, the results match what's in my $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security.java.security file:

> security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
>   security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
>   security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
>   security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
>   security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
>   security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
>   security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
>   security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
>   security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
>   security.provider.10=apple.security.AppleProvider

So I guess my option is to add the AndroidKeyStore provider to this. I'll update this when I've tried that.

Comment: What device was this on?

Comment: Just on an emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there's a bug at the moment with using the AndroidKeyStore with unit tests, which I didn't mention in my original question.

See here:

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1518